# How to link datastore with document using key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search

> I will be very thankful if someone could help me to solve this problem
>   as I have already spent a lot of time on it.
>
> The frontend of my application sends employee data to server end,
>   which creates Emmployee object and saves the data on datastore. My
>   application provides the keyword search functionality on title,
>   company and jobDesc so I am using Search Api.
>
> The problem is that I want to use datastore for storing the complete
>   data and document for storing searchable data. How can I link
>   datastore with document? I know it can be achieved if I set employee’s
>   key as document id but the problem is how will I get the key of the
>   data which is being store. If I try to get key using e.getKey() that
>   obviously returns nullPointerException because it does have the key at
>   that time.
>
> I can achieve this by reading all employee data stored on datastore
>   and creating document with it and setting employee’s key as document
>   id but I want to create document as the data is received from frontend
>   of application.

```
//EmployeeServlet
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    Employee e = new Employee(title, company, location, category,
                    jobType, gender,
                    careerLevel, salaryRange,
                    sector, jobDesc);

            Document newDoc = Document.newBuilder().setId(???)
                    .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("title").setText(title))
                    .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("company").setText(company))
                    .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("jobDesc").setText(jobDesc)).build();

    SearchIndexManager.INSTANCE.indexDocument("Employee", newDoc);


                pm.makePersistent(e);




 //Employee   
    @PersistenceCapable
    public class Employee {
        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        private Key key;
        @Persistent
        private String title;
        @Persistent
        private String company;
        @Persistent
        private String location;
        @Persistent
        private String category;
        @Persistent
        private String jobType;
        @Persistent
        private String gender;
        @Persistent
        private String careerLevel;
        @Persistent
        private String salaryRange;
        @Persistent
        private String sector;
        @Persistent
        private Text jobDescription;


        public Employee(String title, String company, String location,
                String category, 
                String jobType, String gender, 
                String careerLevel, String salaryRange,
                String sector,
                String jobDescription) {
            super();
            this.title = title;
            this.company = company;
            this.location = location;
            this.category = category;
            this.jobType = jobType;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.careerLevel = careerLevel;
            this.salaryRange = salaryRange;
            this.sector = sector;
            this.jobDescription = new Text(jobDescription);
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Save employee entity. Get the id.
2. Set this id as a document id, index the document.

Both steps can be done in the same server call. Just move your makePersistent() before you create a document.

Comment: I my answer helped, you can simply accept it. This is a standard way of saying "Thank you" on StackOverflow :)